# Drop down div when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a HTML page linked with javascript code which allows me to press a button that shows content in a hidden div. The functionality works fine, however when the button is pressed the hidden div displays above the button. Is there anyway it can drop down below the button as opposed to dropping up. Here is the code I am using:

HTML:

```
<div id="spoiler1" style="display:none">
    <p>1. Climb a tree<input type="checkbox"></p>
    <p>2. Roll down a really big hill<input type="checkbox" ></p>
    <p>3. Camp out in the wild<input type="checkbox" ></p>
    <p>4. Build a den<input type="checkbox" ></p>
    <p>5. Skim a stone<input type="checkbox" ></p>
    <p>6. Run around in the rain<input type="checkbox" ></p>
    <p>7. Fly a kte<input type="checkbox" ></p>
    <p>8. Catch a fish with a net<input type="checkbox" ></p>
    <p>9. Eat an apple straight from a tree<input type="checkbox" ></p>
    <p>10. Play conkers<input type="checkbox" ></p>

</div>

<button id="button1" title="Click to show/hide content" type="button1" onclick="readmore1()">Adventurer &#x25BC;</button>
<div id="spoiler1" style="display:none">spoiler text</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function readmore1(){
    var spoiler1 = document.getElementById('spoiler1');
    var btn = document.getElementById('button1');


    if(spoiler1.style.display=='none') {
        spoiler1.style.display = '';
        btn.innerHTML = "Adventurer &#x25B2;";
    } else {
        spoiler1.style.display = 'none';
        btn.innerHTML = "Adventurer &#x25BC;";
    }   
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

CSS:

```
#button1 {

    display: inline-block;
font:  normal 1.5em optima;
line-height: 10px;
margin-left: -10px;
margin-bottom:20px;
width: 250px;
height:60px;
border-radius:8px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: central;
color: #fff;
border: none;
position: relative;
top: -5px;
left: 30px;
```

}

Comment: Could you post your css?

Comment: you meant you want to display the hidden div below the button?

Comment: you should NEVER use an id more then once! spoiler1 is used twice. maybe position:relative; on the parent divs and the button could solve your problem but to be sure you should share your css

Comment: Can't you just place the div after the button?

Answer (score 2):

Hey mate I've looked at your code more in detail and here is a code example on here, I updated your Javascript to Jquery because its a more powerful language :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#spoiler1").hide();
$("#button1").click(function(){
  $("#spoiler1").show();
      });    

   $("#button").click(function(){
$("#spoiler1").hide();
      });    

 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
      <button id="button1" title="Click to show/hide content" type="button1">Adventurer &#x25BC;          </button>
      <button id="button" title="Click to show/hide content" type="button">Hide</button>
<div id="spoiler1" style="display:none">
  <p>1. Climb a tree
    <input type="checkbox">
  </p>
  <p>2. Roll down a really big hill
    <input type="checkbox">
  </p>
  <p>3. Camp out in the wild
    <input type="checkbox">
  </p>
  <p>4. Build a den
    <input type="checkbox">
  </p>
  <p>5. Skim a stone
    <input type="checkbox">
  </p>
  <p>6. Run around in the rain
    <input type="checkbox">
  </p>
  <p>7. Fly a kte
    <input type="checkbox">
  </p>
  <p>8. Catch a fish with a net
    <input type="checkbox">
  </p>
  <p>9. Eat an apple straight from a tree
    <input type="checkbox">
  </p>
  <p>10. Play conkers
    <input type="checkbox">
  </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh also, I think part of the reasonj the buttons were below the div was because how you had coded it in html :)

Comment: Hi Byron, I have just tried changing the code around so it matches the above but it still doesn't work. I get two buttons 'Adventurer' and 'Hide' which when clicked don't reveal anything. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Try adding <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
Above the first script and below the head

Answer (score 0):

Z-index should sort it in the CSS

an example of how to use it below, I hope this helps :)

Here is a code example, I would use 999999 :p thats just an example of how you would do it

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

```
#YourDiv {
Z-Index: 999999
}

#YourButton {
Z-Index:-999999
}
```

Comment: Not really, It is giving you accurate information on Z-index which should help him with this issue. So I would recommend it for this case, maybe not in all cases where it as old HTML properties which aren't compatible but here its fine.

Comment: Maybe that's the case this time, but I recommend to always link to MDN instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: You should probably check that the source is accurate before you start saying that it isn't, there's no need to be upset @wumm

Comment: not to mention... answers with "links" aren't as helpful should a link dry up. Answers should always contain examples of code for future users, as well as a fiddle if possible.

Comment: I've updated it so that there is code examples understandable for anyone.

Comment: Unfortunately the z index hasn't worked, the content is still appearing above the button. Any other ideas as to what it may be?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use CSS for this sort of effects. All you need is "input[type='checkbox']" and label.

**test.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"/>
<input type="checkobx" id="toggleCheck"/>
<label for="toggleCheck">Label for button</label>
<div class="hiddenContent">
   <p>Yours hidden stuff goes here</p>
</div>
```

**test.css**

```
#toggleCheck{ display: none;}
label[for='toggleCheck']{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: green;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}
.hiddenContent{
   display: none;
}
#toggleCheck:checked + label{
    /* Styles for button in opened state*/
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
}
#toggleCheck:checked + label + .hiddenContent{
    display: block;
}
```

With this technique you separate your logic from your views. IMHO, using JS for simple things like that leads to dark side.